# Calculate time difference in excel

Tags: excel, time, difference, date-difference

I have a two dates in excel "1/2/2016 01:56:05" and "8/3/2016 06:21:46". How do I calculate the time difference between them in a format of days and hours?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates are in cells `A1` and `A2`, this will produce an answer with minutes as well in d:hh:mm format.

```
=INT(A2-A1) & ":" & TEXT(A2-A1,"hh:mm")
```

Drop the `:mm` if you don't need minutes.

If you want text:

```
=INT(A2-A1) & " days, " & TEXT(A2-A1,"h") & " hours"
```

If you want text with minutes:

```
=INT(A2-A1) & " days, " & TEXT(A2-A1,"h"" hours, ""m"" minutes""")
```

Using double quotes alongside each other "escapes" the quote itself and allows the extra text to appear in the string.  As Ron stated in his answer, the `m` following an `h` in the same format string indicates minutes, so you can save an extra A2-A1 calculation by putting both in a single format.

Comment: It works, thanks!

But how do I include the minutes for text part?

I tried the below but doesn't seems to work:

=INT(A2-A1) & " days, " & TEXT(A2-A1,"h") & " hours, " & TEXT(A2-A1,"m") & " min"

Answer (score 0):

Try this to include the spelled out hours and minutes:

```
=INT(A2-A1) & " days, " & TEXT(A2-A1,"h "" hours, ""m "" minutes""")
```

Note that since the `m` comes immediately (ignoring the separator text in quotes) after the `h` it will be interpreted as minutes and not months

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to work with dates as decimals. It looks cumbersome, but I'm much happier knowing what it's doing.

What I would usually do is to have A1-A2 in cell A3, then work out the component parts separately:

```
Days: =INT(A3)
Hours: =INT((A3-INT(A3))*24)
Minutes: =INT(((A3*24)-INT(A3*24))*60)
```

Or if you wanted to do it all in one formula:

```
=INT(A3)&" days, "&INT((A3-INT(A3))*24)&" hours, "&INT(((A3*24)-INT(A3*24))*60)&" min"
```

or without using A3

```
=INT(A1-A2)&" days, "&INT(((A1-A2)-INT(A1-A2))*24)&" hours, "&INT((((A1-A2)*24)-INT((A1-A2)*24))*60)&" min"
```

It's not the prettiest or most efficient method but you can see how the times are calculated this way.